# Migrating from single database to multi-tenant database authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

My ASP.NET MVC application was originally developed for a single SQL Server database using OWIN Identity authentication where identity tables and data tables were in the same database.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("defaultConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
}
```

We are now migrating the code to support multi-tenant separate databases model. In this model, the connection string is decided after user enters their credentials (`userid`, `password`, and `companyId`).

`companyId` is the differentiating factor for which connection string to use.  There is no problem here for selecting the data connection string, the problem is setting the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` after user login and not at `Startup:Configuration`

Here is my `ConfigureAuth` class :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

//....
```

I tried a new constructor for ApplicationDbContext which takes "mydb" argument

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string mydb)
        : base(mydb, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

But this is useless at Startup since there is no login credentials then. I am thinking if there is a way to re-initialize `app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);` and pass the "mydb" argument so it uses it for identity store rather then `defaultConnectionString`, this could solve the problem.

My objective here is to have identity tables and data tables in the same database for each tenant and decide on the database after user login.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you find any solution for your problem? I try to implement the same thing (differentiator by OrgId/TenantId) as you.